# How to create the table in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to create the table in javascript. The Td data will from backend

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <th>User Name</th>
                            <th>Manager Name</th>
                            <th>IMEI Number</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>GPS Location</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>183</td>
                            <td>John</td>
                            <td>99999999999</td>
                            <td><span class="label label-success">Edit</span></td>
                            <td>9999</td>
                            <td>99999999999</td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody></table>
```

How to create this format. Like that several rows will be come. and td datas are stored in object. for example obj.name,...

Comment: Iterate and generate the HTML as a string or create DOM elements.

Comment: Simply putting the desired output code won't help you, Share code what you've tried!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create basic elements like this:

```
var myTable = document.createElement('table');
var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
myTable.appendChild(tbody);
```

then you can go in loop and append cells to tbody like this:

```
var numberOfRows = 2;
var numberOfCellsInRow = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
    var tempRow = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = 0; j < numberOfCellsInRow; j++) {
        var tempCell = document.createElement('td');
        tempCell.textContent = 'myCell';
        tempRow.appendChild(tempCell);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tempRow);
}
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lithium182/5NqZ4/)

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery

```
var table = $('<table></table>');
var tbody = $('<tbody></tbody>');
var tr = $('<tr>');
var theader1 =$('<th>User Name</th>');

$(theader1).appendTo(tr);
$(tr).appendTo(tbody);
$(tbody).appendTo(table);

etc...
```

Comment: How to create the table in javascript, not jquery

Answer (score 1):

This is the javascript.

```
var id = document.createElement("table");   

id.innerHTML+='<tr><td width="48"><input type="radio" style="width:3em; height:3em;" name="tableList" value='+table_name+' id="Table'+table_id+'"></td><td width="198" align="center">'+table_name+'</td><td width="168" align="center">'+table_status+'</td></tr>';

document.getElementById("table_display").appendChild(id);
```

This is the HTML

```
<table align="center" height="200" width="420" id="table_display">
</table>
```

Enter your desired data inside the id.innerHTML line instead of table_id and also put headers in the table of body part.

Remove the input type radio. It was used in my project.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tbl=document.createElement('table');
// Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the first position of <thead>:
var row = tbl.insertRow(0);
// Insert a new cell (<td>) at the first position of the "new" <tr> element:
var cell = row.insertCell(0);
// Add some bold text in the new cell:
cell.innerHTML = "<b>obj.name</b>";
```